# React native automatically adds trailing comma to object

Tags: typescript, react-native

I tried to create a new React Native project with Expo.
I added this code to the **App.tsx** :

```
const test = {
  a: "1",
  b: 2    // without trailing comma
};
console.log(test);
```

The result I get in the console is :

```
{
   a: "1",
   b: 2,     // with trailing comma
}
```

I need to send this object as a JSON. And the trailing comma is breaking it.

I don't understand why this trailing comma is automatically added. I can't find a way to remove it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stringify` to parse the object into JSON.

```
const test = {
  a: "1",
  b: 2,  
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(test)); // "{"a":"1","b":2}"
```

Check it out here: https://repl.it/repls/GiddyIrritatingCharacterset

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried that but I need to send an object not a string.

Comment: @SarahT Then you should have a `Content-Type` header as `application/json` and you should be able to send the object even with the trailing comma.

Comment: I am using JsonAPI so I use `Content-Type` header as `application/vnd.api+json`. Does it change anything?

Comment: @SarahT I've never used JSON API, is the server giving you an error with this header and the trailing comma?

Comment: @SarahT I guess you could do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}))`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was an error on the server-side. The JSON was sent correctly.

So, I will close this question. Thanks for the help.